# Using SimpleXml to retrive only a part of an attribute's content: YouTube Video ID

Tags: php, youtube-api, simplexml

Below is a line from an XML feed ( YouTube API 2.1 ):

```
<media:player url='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ksrHwD9cZjQ&amp;feature=youtube_gdata_player'/>
```

How can I use PHP ( SimpleXml ) to retrieve only the video ID which is in our case `ksrHwD9cZjQ` located between `?v=` and `&amp;` ?

I used                `$url = (string)$media->group->player->attributes()->url;` but it retrieves the entire URL.

Regards,

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can further process the url by using `parse_str` to get the video ID in the url:

```
$query_string = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY); // decode `&amp;` to `&`
parse_str($query_string, $data);
echo $data['v']; // ksrHwD9cZjQ
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, and the edit to decode, it wouldn't work without it.

Appreciated, have a nice day !